# Access phpmyadmin (which is on a non-standard port) from my office network

Tags: web-server, port

On my webserver I have set up phpmyadmin to operate over port 8084 for security reasons.
So to access it I would normally visit http://mywebsite.com:8084

In my office, it seems like this port is blocked for outgoing connections. When I try to access phpmyadmin the page just hangs and I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I can access phpmyadmin fine on my mobile using cellular signal.

Is there a way to access my phpmyadmin on my office pc given that this port seems to be blocked?

Comment: Rather than trying to work around security policy, you should speak to your network administrator as you obviously have a legitimate business need to have port 8084 opened on your network.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you are more secure just by not using the standard port for HTTP.

There are more chances that standard ports for HTTP and HTTPS are opened for outgoing connections at your office, so your safest bet to secure a `phpmyadmin` installation is to run a secured web server and use [mutual SSL authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/configure-ssl-mutual-two-way-authentication):

```
Listen                   443 https
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  DocumentRoot           "/srv/www/html"
  ServerAdmin            admin@company.com
  SSLCACertificateFile   /etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem
  SSLCertificateFile     /etc/pki/tls/private/phpmyadmin.domain.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/pki/tls/private/phpmyadmin.domain.com/key.pem
  SSLCARevocationCheck   chain
  SSLCARevocationFile    /etc/pki/CA/crl/crl.pem
  SSLEngine              on
  SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
  SSLVerifyClient        require
  SSLVerifyDepth         5
  ServerName             phpmyadmin.domain.com
  RewriteEngine          on
  RewriteCond            %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
  RewriteCond            %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule            . - [F]
  Alias                  /console /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
  ErrorLog               "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -L /var/log/httpd/phpmyadmin/error.log -f /var/log/httpd/phpmyadmin/error.log.%Y%m%d 86400"
  CustomLog              "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -L /var/log/httpd/phpmyadmin/access.log -f /var/log/httpd/phpmyadmin/access.log.%Y%m%d 86400" combinedio

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    Require              ssl
    Require              ssl-verify-client
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 256
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Company" \
                     and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "Development" \
                     and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"}
    SSLRenegBufferSize   131072
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
    Require              ssl
    Require              ssl-verify-client
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 128
    SSLRequire           %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O}  eq "Comapny" \
                     and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "Development" \
                     and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} in {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"}
    SSLRenegBufferSize   131072
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from All
      Allow from None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from All
      Allow from None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from All
      Allow from None
  </Directory>

  # This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
  # filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
  #
  #<IfModule mod_security.c>
  #    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
  #        SecRuleInheritance Off
  #    </Directory>
  #</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

You could further secure such a server by using a limited list of allowed IPs (`Deny` and `Allow` directives), and configuring `mod_security`, `mod_evasive` and `fail2ban`, for example.

Comment: I agree with your statement and it would be a superior way to go but I only rarely use phpmyadmin - I just need it right now for a specific task. It just happened that I put it on 8084 to keep it out the way of other sites on the server. So is there no way to access phpmyadmin without moving to a connection where the port is open?

Comment: Use name-based virtual hosting so you can use standard ports. It is easier to do that that trying to circumvent the security measures of your office, which is not on-topic here